# how to Collect number values of php array and put in variable

Tags: php, arrays, function

i have this array

```
 array (size=12)
  0 => 21
  1 => 16
  2 => 78
  3 => 80
  4 => 113
  5 => 82
```

**and i want to  collect all values and put it in one variable 
(note :array is changeable for each user)** ?

Comment: What do you mean put all values in a variable? By sum? Concatenation? Multiplication?

Comment: yes i want it  by sum

Comment: Theres a php function `array_sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you are referring by collecting, eg: if you want the sum of the array , you can simply use  :

> array_sum($your_array)

If you need to collect the array content as a string with a delimiter (21,16,etc.), you can use :

> implode(',', $your_array)